# NSApplicationDelegate's applicationDidFinishLaunching is not being called

Tags: swift, macos, cocoa, nsapplication-delegate

I've been trying to play with Swift 3, but I am unable to get started. The following code is compiling, however it does not log anything. Looks like `applicationDidFinishLaunching` is not being called. Am I missing some critical piece here?

**Sources/main.swift**:

```
import AppKit

class AppDelegate: NSObject, NSApplicationDelegate {
    func applicationDidFinishLaunching(aNotification: NSNotification) {
        NSLog("application start")
    }
}

NSApplication.shared()
NSApp.setActivationPolicy(.regular)
let controller = AppDelegate()
NSApp.delegate = controller
NSApp.run()
```

p.s. There is a similar question about `applicationDidFinishLaunching` being called but not printing anything. I believe that this is not the case, as having `window.orderFrontRegardless()` instead of logging also has no effect for me.

```
System Version: OS X 10.11.6

> swift --version
Apple Swift version 3.0 (swiftlang-800.0.43.6 clang-800.0.38)
Target: x86_64-apple-macosx10.9
```

Comment: As far as I know, `NSApplicationDelegate` does not define a method `application(_:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:)`. Aren't you confusing `NSApplicationDelegate.applicationDidFinishLaunching(_:)` with `UIApplicationDelegate.application(_:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:)`?

Comment: Thank you for pointing this out. I've made changes to the question. Effects are unfortunatelly still the same

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to implement Objective-C protocols in Swift 3, you need to use `_` indicating the method has no label for the first parameter.

```
func applicationDidFinishLaunching(_ aNotification: Notification) {
```

(UPDATE)

Sorry, in my first code, I have forgotten to to replace `NSNotification` with `Notification`. (Thanks, Leo Dabus.)

Comment: For example:

`main.swift:229:10: warning: instance method 'applicationDidFinishLaunching' nearly matches optional requirement 'applicationDidFinishLaunching' of protocol 'NSApplicationDelegate'
    func applicationDidFinishLaunching(_ aNotification: NSNotification) {
         ^`

Comment: Try dropping the NS from NSNotification

Comment: That's answers the question I've asked, but interestingly, don't solve my issue with opening window. I'll play around and probably ask another question later.

Comment: To be honest I don't really "want" to implement Objective-C protocols. What I am trying to do is to write a minimal gui app in a "swift 3 way", but searching for any docs I either find swift2 or iOS related articles, which I cannot find a way to adapt

Answer (score 3):

I'd a similar problem where `func applicationDidFinishLaunching(_ aNotification: Notification)` was not getting called.

For me, the issue was with the **App Delegate referencing outlet**.

[image]

> **Solution: Just removing it and then connecting it back had resolved the issue for me.**

This is how you can recreate a connection

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The line where you refer to, but don't use `NSApplication.shared` looks like a typo. If you replace it with `NSApp = NSApplication.shared`, and make sure the method signature in AppDelegate is correct it, should work.

Answer (score 0):

for me... I had no windows visible at launch.
As soon as I ticked that box on one of the windows, applicationDidFinishLaunching was called when I ran the app.

Comment: You should update your answer with a clarification of what box you ticked. It's not clear what you are referring to.

Comment: "visible at launch"